# LD_PRELOAD radically reduces process creation performance for C under linux?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, ld-preload

I was investigating a severe performance hit in `UNIXBENCH`'s `spawn.c` portion of it's benchmark which measures process creation speed:

https://code.google.com/p/byte-unixbench/source/browse/trunk/UnixBench/src/spawn.c

I could not understand why when running under centos I was getting very low numbers (even stalling or halting of the process) and then if I temporarily booted into debian, the performance was exponentially higher.

I eventually tracked it down to the fact I was preloading `jemalloc` 3.6 via `/etc/ld.so.preload` which is a replacement high performance memory allocator:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919

Is this performance hit because every spawned process is loading it's own copy of jemalloc?

Is there a way to avoid that and still have jemalloc auto-load? Why doesn't it share the library?

Comment: This may be unrelated to library preloading and most likely has to do with the way your OS evicts file-backed memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does jemalloc have any other dependencies (like pthread)? If so the additional load time cost might add up, and in the case of pthread, it might cause some functions that could be lock-free in single-threaded applications to actually take locks, slowing them down. In any case, even just mapping an additional library into the process's address space and performing relocations takes a significant amount of time, so if the program being timed is minimal (I can't tell from your link exactly what's being timed) then execution time might be dominated by the work the dynamic linker does.